# How can I make a new page in ActiveReports

Tags: activereports

I'm working by using ActiveReports

I want to know how can I make a new page

```
this.DataSource = data;
```

data is collection. So, it will return multiple lines. I want to draw each data to NEW PAGE.
Please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the line of code you've shared, it appears you're using a SectionReport. In a SectionReport, to draw each record on a new page, you can simply set the NewPage property of the Detail section to 'After'. Please see following documentation link for more info: http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR11/index.html#GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v11~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.Detail~NewPage.html